# Extract file names, with a certain extension, and their sizes in a txt file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a directory that looks like this

```
dir 
 |--folder1
 |     |--- subfolder1
 |     |--- ...
 |     |--- subfolder100
 |
 |--folder2 
      |--- subfolder1
      |--- ...
      |--- subfolder100
```

Each folder and subfolder contains among others files with the extension `".fq.gz"`

I want to list all files with a `.fq.gz` question , and copy their `filenames` and `file size` in a `.txt` file.

I want something like this.

While I know how to copy the file names

```
ls -R | grep "\.fq.gz" > ${destination}output.txt
```

it becomes rather complicated to add the file size. I am taking an error that the file does not exist

I want something like this

```
less data.txt 

file1.fq.gz  43434343
file2.fq.gz  43454854
....
```

Comment: Have you tried "tree | xargs ls -l".  This works on my Mac if file names do not have any space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU find:

```
find . -name '*.fq.gz' -printf '%f %s\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS Terminal:

```
find . -name "*.fq.gz"| xargs ls -l
```

Then, you can easily parse file names and sizes using `awk`

OR

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec du -h {} \;
```